# Aspx file in two master pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a page on a website that uses a master page and a child page. I would like to use the child page to create a new page on the website, but with a different master page.

Is it possible to do this without duplicating the code for the child page? 
To make it clearer I have also added a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N66H0.png) to a picture of the layouts used for the two pages.

In the picture, both children use the same code.

Edit: I have also thought about using a control for this, but I am not sure if this is the proper solution. The child page is pretty big and complex and also uses a lot of JavaScript.

Comment: what about changing Master page file at `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/YourMasterPage.master" ` ?

Comment: @zey That would  not work because I want it to behave like two different pages. This would only make one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading the child page, you can [set the master page dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) in code, in the `PreInit` event.  Something like this:

```
void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/NewMaster.master";
}
```

That way your child page can set its master page based on whatever condition you would have in your site.